# Right modification of a poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-process

I have an classical service random distribution where customers appear after random period of time.
I have a multiple services working in different geo regions. Some very local - one city, some global.

The problem is the night time: there is 10x less activity during nights:
(night time in blue)

[image: Img]

I can not "hardcode" that fluctuations because they are different from service to service because of time zone shift and different geo area - whole US would be working in 3 TZs and whole Norway would be only one so "wave" function will have a different fall/raise angle and ratio of low/high activity time frame.

My ultimate goal is to calculate probability of "service down" vs "no customers" at the given moment.
Example: If no customers completed their purchases from 2 hours ago till now, what are the chances that the service is down vs no one really came to buy in 2 hours?
Practically no purchase in 2 hours during day is 99% chance that service is down but not during night and not for services with very low use. You need to wait longer or simply ignore service monitoring during **predicted** low traffic period.

How can I adjust my distribution to those daily fluctuations?

Comment: You need to better describe if/how you aggreggate different geo areas. The simplest is to model arrivals as a *non-homogeneous* Poisson process with intensity functions estimated from the above graph. That would also allow you to add up customers over separate (time-shifted) regions to obtain a total process.

Comment: @a.s. I am not aggregating data from different geos and just figuring out a distribution for individual geo. Can you advice the intensity function that needs to be applied and how it should be done from math stand point? A link would be helpful.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you final goal is - modeling arriving distribution, modeling the whole queue (if so, what are service times?). But in simplest terms, you estimate intensity $\lambda(t)=\frac{\text{# of customers arriving in } [t-\delta t,t+\delta t] \text{ window}}{2\delta t}$ where the window choice might depend on $t$. You could also fit some mathematically convinient $\lambda$ to your data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/poisson/Nonhomogeneous.html for general theoretical overview.

Comment: @a.s. I've updated the question with a goal description - last paragraph.

Comment: Bogdan, when asking an *applied* question, you gotta give a thorough description of your problem so it could be modeled appropriately. How many servers do you have? What are causes of service going down? Present data on the times of actual failures. What are repair times? What is the gray line on your graph? Once you have your Poisson intensity for arrival, probability of no arrivals at window $W$ $p_0^c=\exp(-\int_W \lambda)$. Then you determine the chances of service going down $p_d$ in that Window and that gives chances if each one given that no customers were served.

Comment: How many servers do you have? - around 100. I have no idea why it matters. I am figuring out a distribution and probability of down time individually. What are causes of service going down? - Any. No idea why it matters. I just want an algorithm to know if it is down or not. I just need to tell operator "Something is probably broken. Go and check". What are repair time? Pretty much out of scope. What is a grey line? I can make it configurable easily if I get my model right.  Is the no-arrivals formula given with a night time frame adjustment?